# google plus app does not return back to my iOS app while integration of google plus in iOS app in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-plus

i have followed developer.google.com official documentation "https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in#before_you_begin"
    in order to make google plus authentication in ios app but after authentication it does not return back to my app rather it takes me "google.co.in" site after displying "safari can't open the page because of invalid address" dialog box for a second or two. i have read many issues related to it but nothing helped me in my case. also i checked my bundle id  and url scheme  and both are same in my project info.plist as well as in google plus app settings . i stuck on this problem since many days. so please help me on this. 
    for your knowledge i am using xcode 5.1 and ios 7.

```
Thanks and waiting for the help.
```

Comment: please some one who know the answer help me on this.otherwise i am out of my job.

Answer (score 2):

Check following possibilities.

*1) Use the correct app id,that used to register in Google developer site.(App won't return back after login if this ID is wrong)
2)Check whether you correctly given the URL Scheme in Target-->Info-->Url types.*

Comment: i fulfill both your possibilities and both are correct in my app.but still not working. my url scheme which is same as bundle id  start with integer (9xxx.xxxxxx). is this can be a source of problem.thanks for help.

Comment: i added my bundle identifier to the URL Scheme box and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Add bundle identifier to the URL Scheme in info.plist